# Jquery datatable column headers width issue with vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, datatables

I m working with datatables for the first time and got struck with the below explained issue..
Whenever i m trying to include vertical scroll , column headers losses all itz alignment, all the column width reduces and as a result will get header row who's length is  half of the entire table.

One more thing i ve noticed is that, in the th class style width is coming as 0px, can any one pls temme why it's coming so ? 
js part i ve included,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url :"",

                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data) 
                    {
                            $('#customers').dataTable(
                            {
                            "aaData":data.response,
                            "aoColumns": [
                            { "sTitle": "Rendering Engine", "bSortable": false},
                            { "sTitle": "Broswers", "bSortable": false },
                            { "sTitle": "Platform", "bSortable": false }
                            ],
                         "sScrollY": "250px",
                        "iDisplayLength": 200,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": false
                           });
                    }   
                });
            });
```

and html part

```
<table id="customers"></table>
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: If it's not just a typo, you've messed up with the quotes ? Three quotes in 'url' will start a new string that now inludes dataType etc...

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by wrapping the "dataTable" Table with a div with overflow:auto

```
.dataTables_scroll
{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

and add this JS after your dataTable initialization

```
jQuery('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');
```

Dont use sScrollX or sScrollY, remove then and add a div wrapper yourself which does the same thing.

Comment: For printing issue also add @media print{ .dataTables_scroll{overflow:visible!important;} }

Comment: This doesn't work, as now the header is part of the single table and will scroll with the rest of the table body.

Comment: Perfect! as simple as ABC..Vote up...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    success : function(data) 
                {
                        $('#customers').dataTable(
                        {
                        "aaData":data.response,
                        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sTitle": "Rendering Engine", "bSortable": false},
                        { "sTitle": "Broswers", "bSortable": false },
                        { "sTitle": "Platform", "bSortable": false }
                        ],
                     "sScrollX": "100%",
                     "sScrollY": "250px",
                    "iDisplayLength": 200,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "aLengthMenu": [50,100,250,500],
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                       });
                }   





  //use this style
 <style type="text/css">

       .dataTables_length {
       float: left;
       width: 40%;
        }

    .dataTables_filter {
      float: right;
      text-align: right;
      width: 50%;
      } 

  .dataTables_info {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*min-height: 100%;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
  }
</style>
```

Comment: The problem with the column headers is that ..once the scroll is added ,the  column headers are coming as a table of width 0px.. I m getting confused of how to manage the styles of tht table

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your table is empty. I've seen similar issues in the past, they were always caused by your table not having a `<thead>` / `<tbody>`.

Change your HTMl to:

```
<table id="customers">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know what happens.